# kinit fails on freeipa master: File or directory not found

Tags: fedora, freeipa

An upgrade from Fedora 36 to Fedora 38 has completely broken Kerberos authentication in our Freeipa realm.
`kinit <username>` fails for every user but our domain admin. Hosts can't authenticate themselves, too.
Everything works fine if I add `disable_pac = true` in the `/etc/krb5.conf`. However, this isn't a recommended setting from a security point of view. Therefore, we can't accept that as a workaround.
I found several posts suggesting generating sids for the users. So I did that by calling `ipa config-mod --enable-sid --add-sids`. The job run without any error and assigned a sid to each user. I confirmed this with `ipa user show --all`.

I also verified that the firewall configuration matches the [recommondations of freeipa](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Active_Directory_trust_setup#iptables)
I also thought this issue was caused by a Freeipa version mismatch between our two master servers. Therefore, I updated both servers to Fedora 38, but the problem still exists.

I tried to collect the vital system information. I'd appreciate any help since I am stuck here.

```
$ kinit user
Passwort für user@INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE:
kinit: allgemeiner Fehler (siehe E-Text) bei Anfängliche Anmeldedaten werden geholt.
```

the `/var/log/krb5kdc.log` contains the following entries for an authentication attempt:

```
Nov 25 20:22:35 id.intern.example.de krb5kdc[2858](Information): AS_REQ (6 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), camellia256-cts-cmac(26), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), camellia128-cts-cmac(25)}) 141.83.153.180: HANDLE_AUTHDATA: user@INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE für krbtgt/INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE@INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE, Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

The content of our `/etc/krb5.conf` is:

```
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 rdns = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = true
 udp_preference_limit = 0
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE = {
  kdc = id.intern.example.de:88
  master_kdc = id.intern.example.de:88
  kpasswd_server = id.intern.example.de:464
  admin_server = id.intern.example.de:749
  default_domain = intern.example.de
  pkinit_anchors = FILE:/var/lib/ipa-client/pki/kdc-ca-bundle.pem
  pkinit_pool = FILE:/var/lib/ipa-client/pki/ca-bundle.pem
}

[domain_realm]
 .intern.example.de = INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE
 intern.example.de = INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE
 id.intern.example.de = INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE

[dbmodules]
  INTERN.EXAMPLE.DE = {
    db_library = ipadb.so
  }

[plugins]
 certauth = {
  module = ipakdb:kdb/ipadb.so
  enable_only = ipakdb
 }
```

IPA diagnostics show no error:

```
$ ipactl status
Directory Service: RUNNING
krb5kdc Service: RUNNING
kadmin Service: RUNNING
named Service: RUNNING
httpd Service: RUNNING
ipa-custodia Service: RUNNING
pki-tomcatd Service: RUNNING
ipa-otpd Service: RUNNING
ipa-dnskeysyncd Service: RUNNING
ipa: INFO: The ipactl command was successful
```

Please let me know, if I forgot to include anything vital.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not using freeipa-users@ mailing list to ask your questions? There is pretty much nobody who tracks serverfault for FreeIPA-related questsions (except, may be me, occasionally) here on Serverfault.

Please make a post to freeipa-users@ with details of your specific user, krb5kdc.log and dirsrv error log entries (if possible, use English-based locale in the logs or provide proper translation alongside). Also provide output of `ipa idrange-find` command.